# DataGrid is not included inside of "this" context in subscribe scope in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, instance, subscribe

In my Angular project, a page includes 2 components named "head" and "product"..

In "head", I can change the currency of page.. I keep the currency information in localStorage.. When the currency is changed, I push a random number by "next" as below:

`this.service.refreshNumberOfAllPriceByCurrency.next(Math.random()); //"refreshNumberOfAllPriceByCurrency" is defined as ReplaySubject<any>(1) in service component.`

This line is triggering subscribe in "product" component as below:

```
constructor(.........)
{
   this.service.refreshNumberOfAllPriceByCurrency.subscribe(number => {
        this.gridProduct.instance.refresh();
        this.gridPrice.instance.refresh();
   });
}
```

When debugging inside of subscribe scope, "this" context doesn't contain gridProduct, gridPrice and linensOfferId. So it can not get the instance of "undefined"…

How can I get the instance of these grids inside of subscribe scope?

Thanks in advance…

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe in ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on stackblitz?

Comment: Hi Wctiger.. I tried ngAfterViewInit. Nothing changed.

Comment: Please specify how you are instantiating gridProduct and gridPrice. If you are getting an error that they are undefined, then they are not being instantiated when you intend them to be.

Comment: I am instantiating the grids like that:

@ViewChild("gridProduct", { static: false }) gridProduct: any;
 @ViewChild("gridPrice", { static: false }) gridPrice: any;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. "this.service.refreshNumberOfAllPriceByCurrency.subscribe()" event is in constructor. I modified the code as below:

```
constructor()
{
   var this2=this;

   this.service.refreshNumberOfAllPriceByCurrency.subscribe(number => {
       if (this2.linensOfferId > 0) {
           this2.gridProduct.instance.refresh();
           this2.gridPrice.instance.refresh();
       }
   });
}
```

Before subscribe(), I defined this2 and it is equal to "this". By this way, I can reach this context fully from inside of subscribe() scope…

Thank you…